# How to create input tensors and use with interpreter in Tensorflow Lite (experimental C API)?

Tags: c, tensorflow, tensor

How do we create tensors in Tensorflow Lite with the C API? And then how do we use them with the interpreter?

I understand that Tensorflow Lite has documentation for the C++ API, and regular Tensorflow has documentation out there for the C API. However, there is little-to-no information on using the C API for Lite.

The Lite C++ API has a function for creating tensors but I don't see that anywhere in the C API header file (or any other related headers/source files) for Lite.

The following exists in an example of using the regular Tensorflow C API. But it doesn't seem to exist in the TF Lite C API.

```
TF_Tensor* input_tensor = tf_utils::CreateTensor(TF_FLOAT, input_dims.data(), input_dims.size(), input_vals.data(), input_vals.size() * sizeof(float));
```

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow Lite tensors (`TFL_Tensor`) are owned by an interpreter (`TFL_Interpreter`) instance, and cannot be created by the user. You can get handles to input/output tensors using the following methods:

```
 TFL_Tensor* TFL_InterpreterGetInputTensor(
    const TFL_Interpreter* interpreter, int32_t input_index);

 const TFL_Tensor* TFL_InterpreterGetOutputTensor(
    const TFL_Interpreter* interpreter, int32_t output_index);
```

Tensor data can be read (or updated) using the methods described in the [`c_api.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/c/c_api.h#L177) header. The documentation is lacking as this remains an experimental API, but we expect to move to move it out of experimental in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was wondering if you had any insight on what the input_index and output_index variables mean as well? I've just been putting in 0 but I'm not sure if that's correct.

For some background, I'm inputting a 1x1x6 dimension tensor and expecting a 1x1x1 dimension tensor.

Comment: The index corresponds to the original order of input tensor names that were provided when the model was converted. You can check the inputs/outputs of your model using the visualization tool (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/faq#how_do_i_inspect_a_tflite_file) or with something like Netron. If you model only has 1 input, you can just use index 0 (see also `TFL_InterpreterGetInputTensorCount()`).  Likewise if your model has 1 output, you can also just use index 0.